# android : parse.com object not found for update

Tags: android, parse-platform, relation, parse-server

I have a class `Post` with ACL set to public read and owner(read & write), however I also have a Relation `<ParseUser>` likes, column where I store pointers to user objects.

On my personal Parse Server setup, I am able to add new user objects to the relation, with the above specified Permissions (ACL), however on parse.com, an exception is thrown with the message:

> Object not found for update" with the same ACL

Is this normal behavior or I just found a bug in Parse Server?

Answer (score 0):

Checking your parse database for this column his ACL is Change as private so this first manually change it.
Then after you can run your code with set your ACL permission before save in background method is run.